# Generate clean short unique ID from MongoDB object id

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm working on a MERN patient monitoring system app, which requires generating unique patient ID for each patient. MongoDB object IDs are not user friendly for real time applications. So how can I modify an ID like this, "6260156170355cbf6ec668g4" to display on the frontend as a clean, short unique patient ID for each patient?

Also is there is any way to generate unique sequential IDs from object IDs?

Comment: I suggest sticking with generated MongoId or use [UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) as a unique identifier. Mongo doesn't support sequential auto-increment, event that is possible to implement it, please refer to [MongoDB Auto-Increment](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate short ids, try out nano id (https://github.com/ai/nanoid/).